# read() issue with Serial Communication in C

Tags: c, serial-port, termios

I am trying to communicate with a tty device (Telit modem, so AT commands), but I am having trouble using read(). Opening and Writing are working (which I test by having a cat /dev/ttyACM0 session open while I run my code), but read always returns a random address. I have not messed around with a lot of terminal settings, so that is probably the main issue.

Could someone point me in the right direction for setting the correct terminal properties to read correctly?

Currently, stty returns these settings as default after rebooting the Telit chip (except baud rate is set by me)

```
>> stty -F /dev/ttyACM0
     speed 921600 baud; line = 0;  
     -brkint -imaxbel
```

And here are a few of the terminal settings I've used with no luck.

```
terminal_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
terminal_settings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
terminal_settings.c_cflag &= ~ICANON;
terminal_settings.c_cflag |= CREAD;
terminal_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
terminal_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
```

Comment: `read()` doesn't return an address at all.  It returns the number of bytes read, or -1 in the event of an error.

Comment: In any event, if you want us to help you figure out what's wrong with your code, then it would behoove you to present a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: You need to establish how you want to perform I/O before you write your program.  Canonical or non-canonical?  (AT commands could use canonical.)  Blocking or non-blocking?  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  You need to use the **stty** command with the  `-a` switch

Comment: And you probably should use a slower, more sensible baudrate.  It's unlikely that a modem defaults to 921600 on a serial link.